# How to generate an index at end of a PDF file?

Tags: c#, pdf

Given an existing PDF document, I would like to tack on an index to the end of the file to show the pages on which key words show up.  It would be best if I don't have to give a list of words to look for and the list of words is automatically generated.  However, if a list of words must be given, I can work with it.  I'm looking to do this either through a C# library or a command line tool.  It needs to run as part of another command line app.

Is there anything out there that is capable of this?

This "PDF Index Everthing" (http://www.pdfstore.com/details.asp?ProdID=799) seems to be on the right track, but requires interaction through its GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I don't actually have an c# solution but hopefully this will still help...*

**[pdflib](http://pdflib.com/)** is an excellent pdf development library. It is one of the better libs available. As far as I know it doesn't have a C# binding. PDF is a random access object-based file format and although there are many libraries that allow for creating of pdfs, most freely available libs don't support adding pages to existing pdfs. **pdflib** does support adding pages with it's pdi option, so it may be worth checking out.

**Updated Info:**

Check out- [iText# library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) and

[merging pdf files with C# and iText](http://alex.buayacorp.com/merge-pdf-files-with-itext-and-net.html)